# How to combine group by, where and logical operators?

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, where-clause

I have the following data structure

```
| Name  | Contract Type |
|:------|--------------:|
| Frank | Student       |
| Frank | Staff         |
| Frank | Staff         |
| John  | Internship    |
| John  | Student       |
| John  | Staff         |
| Tim   | Internship    |
| Tim   | Staff         |
```

I want to get the `Names` of employees who have had a student contract and another contract in theire history. My approach was

```
Select Name, count(Name) from table
where ContractType = ('Student') AND (ContractType = ('Staff') OR ContractType = ('Internship') )     
group by Name having count (Name) > 1
```

The problem here is that I still get all employees. Anyone who can help me get this accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by the `Name` and take only those groups having at least once the Student contract and in total more than 1 contract

```
Select Name
from your_table
group by Name 
having sum(case when ContractType = 'Student' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and count(distinct ContractType) > 1
```

Comment: Isnt weird you use a `SUM` to count, and then `COUNT` ? I would use `COUNT` on both to keep consistency and is more clear what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza: I don't agree. With conditional aggregation counting with `SUM` is equally common as with `COUNT`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Using aggregational `count()` requires to know that `count()`  does not count NULL values but everything else.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza There's nothing weird with it, you just need to know what `SUM` and `COUNT` do. And there's no need to *keep consistency* IMO when using functions, since they are used to evaluate different things

Comment: @Lamak Ok then. Looks like is just weird to me. Maybe the OCD is stronger on me  :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Name
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN [Contract Type] = 'Student' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
AND SUM(CASE WHEN [Contract Type] <> 'Student' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1;
```

But you can also use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Name
FROM dbo.YourTable A
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable
             WHERE Name = A.Name
             AND [Contract Type] = 'Student')
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable
            WHERE Name = A.Name
            AND [Contract Type] <> 'Student');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a GROUP BY and then IN:

```
SELECT name
FROM table
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
AND name IN
(SELECT name
 FROM table
 WHERE contracttype = 'student')
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38fa36/1

Comment: That won't work because the `and name in ()` part is not in a `where` clause but in the `having` clause.

Comment: Naw it still works. The WHERE is inside a subquery so we're good. Have a look here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38fa36/1

Comment: OP is using SQL Server and not MySQL. And this "feature" of MySQL causes more confusion that it is of use.

Comment: @juergend this works fine in SQL Server, no problem at all

Comment: @juergend to be completely honest, I didn't think so either, so I tried it and was surprised that it did work

Comment: This is not surprising at all. `name` is in the group by clause, so of course you can use it in the having clause.